# SpringBoot App with REST api to connect to LDAP- automatically configure LdapContextSource

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-ldap

I am developing a SpringBoot app with one REST API to check if a user exists on the LDAP instance I am connecting to. I am currently pulling the LdapContextSource properties from the application.properties file.
Is there a way I can automatically configure the LdapContextSource so that everytime the API is called I don't have to setup the LdapContextSource configuration?

```
@RestController
public class CheckUserController {

@Value("${ldap.base}")
String ldapBase;

@Value("${ldap.url}")
String ldapUrl;

@Value("${ldap.userDn}")
String userDn;

@Value("${ldap.password}")
String ldapPassword;

@Autowired
LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

@PostMapping(value = "/checkUser")
public ResponseEntity checkUser(@RequestHeader("x-user-id") String userID){

LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setBase(ldapBase);
    contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
    contextSource.setUserDn(userDn);
    contextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);
    contextSource.setPooled(false);
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    
ldapTemplate.setContextSource(contextSource);

ldapTemplate.search(....search for user)

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!
Check please this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-ldap
I followed it step by step and it works perfectlly. It is like working with JPA repository, but you use LDAP repository.

Comment: Thanks @Tufisi Radu. The configuration that I was looking for was actually contained in the link at the top of the page which directs to here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-ldap